# How to determine the no of enum items declared in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I need to know the number of enums that have been declared.
So far I am using the following which works but I wonder if there is a better way?

```
 enum MyEnum 
 {
  foo = 1,
  bar = 2
 }

int noOfEnums = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Count();
```

noOfEnums will be 2;

Comment: `Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length` is slightly better. :)

Comment: @Dmitry d'oh, just what I was about to say ;p

Comment: @Dmitry Why is this better?

Comment: Because the length of an array is not calculated each time you access it in contrast with enumerating an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use:

```
enum MyEnum 
{
  foo = 1,
  bar = 2
}

var noOfEnums = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length;
```

The length property of this array equals the number of items defined in the enum

Also check [Count Items in a C# Enum](http://www.csharp411.com/c-count-items-in-an-enum/)